# Could not find method buildTypes()

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jgFH.png)[image]

I am facing this issue

> Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_3r52yusiev35zn4cvwce7kc4y$_run_closure1$_closure3@16d58fc] on root project 'testapp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   Open File

Comment: Your markdown image was not properly included in your post. Your title was also way too long. Please, also add your code directly to your post... Not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find method buildTypes()

That's because you have incorrectly placed the `buildTypes` inside your `build.gradle`. It must be inside your `android` block in your **module** `build.gradle`. Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    // your app config
    ...
  }

  // your buildTypes here. It's must be inside the android block
  buildTypes {
    ...
  }

}

dependencies {
  // your dependencies.
  ...
}
```

You need to consult [The module-level build file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level) documentation for details.

Your current `build.gradle` picture is looks like the **root** `build.gradle` of your project. Visit [The top-level build file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#top-level) for details about it.

Comment: i placed the buildtypes{} inside the android block

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? If yes, share the project root/build.gradle and app/build.gradle.